# Push notifications not working in release version on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

After we published our application to the appstore, push notifications stoped working.
If I install application by xcode with release mode it's ok, but if I install application with appstore or testflight it doesn't work.

What I may miss?

Comment: I think the APNS certificate you used is developer certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using APNS Distribution certificate on your server side.

Comment: I'm using Distribution certificate, it's ok

Comment: Also need to remove sandbox (sandbox mode) from push notification url in push sending script.

Comment: I'm using com.notnoop.apns:apns. It's ok too.